# /testforblock command on beacon beam

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can you use the testforblock command on a beacon's beam?
[image]

So, if there is a beam above the beacon, the testforblock command will turn on, for it found a beacon's beam. Can this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the beam is neither a block nor entity to detect.

You can check whether or not the beacon tile entity has a `Levels` integer tag of a certain value, which indicates how many valid layers of the pyramid there are for the beacon. For example, if there was only one level of the pyramid, the `Levels` value will be 1:

```
/testforblock X Y Z minecraft:beacon -1 {Levels:1}
```

Alternatively, you can check for a value of 0 and invert the signal to cover all possible levels.

Comment: I'm making a map where it checks if the light beam can go all the way through the glass with no blocks blocking it successfully. Can this method work?

Comment: @Akidus Yes, `Levels` will be 0 if the beam was blocked.

Comment: Okay. How would I put this in a command block , if the beam was right next to the command block?  Never mind. Got it.

Comment: Or, is there a way to do this with specific colors?

Comment: @Akidus The only way to detect the color is to manually check for stained glass above the beacon, which could take a lot of work (to the point of probably not being feasible) if allowing them to be placed both at any height and mixing colors.